# Weird Debugging Behavior with Struct That Contains a UUID

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

Consider this struct:

```
struct test
{
    var id:UUID = UUID()
    var name:String = ""
}
```

When executing the following line of code:

```
var myTest : test?
```

The debugger correctly shows myTest = nil

Then I execute:

```
myTest = test()
```

The debugger still shows MyTest = nil

If I remove the id variable from the struct, the debugger correctly shows a value for myTest.

It seems that whenever I have a UUID in the struct it does this.

Is this a bug in Xcode11, or am I missing something?

Here is a screenshot after declaring myTest showing it nil as expected:

[image]

Here is a screenshot after setting myTest to test(), and printing it. You can see that the print shows the initialized structure, but the debug window still shows myTest as nil:

[image]

Comment: And if you init `id = UUID()` , still the same issue?

Comment: Yes, same issue. I edited my question to reflect this, and added some screenshots to show what I am seeing.

Comment: Im confused... what should the debugger be showing then ? You haven't appended any data... so shouldnt it be NIL ?

Comment: in the second screenshot, myTest does indeed have data. It was initialized by line 24, and printed on line 25. Note that the process is currently in break on line 26. The print output shows a UUID value for "id", and an empty string for "name."

If I remove "id" from the structure, when in break at line 26, the debugger value for myTest properly shows the variable as having a value and displays the "name" member.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you think this is unexpected behaviour. 
If you were to have a struct like so:

```
struct test {
    var name: String = ""
}
```

By doing so

```
var myTest: test?

myTest = test()

print(myTest)
```

result: `Optional(__lldb_expr_7.test(name: ""))`

Even if you were to add in a UUID like so :

```
struct test {
    var id: UUID = UUID(uuid: UUID_NULL)
    var name: String = ""
}
```

and did the same thing

```
var myTest: test?
myTest = test()
print(myTest)
```

Result: `Optional(__lldb_expr_9.test(id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, name: ""))`

You are still given the structure

if you had a struct like so

```
struct test {
    var id: UUID = UUID(uuid: UUID_NULL)
    var name: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""
}
```

and still did the same thing...

```
var myTest: test?

myTest = test()

print(myTest)
```

result: `Optional(__lldb_expr_11.test(id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, name: "", lastName: ""))`

you are still given back results...

The results are all nill or empty strings as defined in the struct...

we can then append to the struct like so

```
var myTest: test?

myTest = test(id: some_UUID_Number_Here, name: "Jack", lastName: "Sparrow")

print(myTest as Any)
```

result: `Optional(__lldb_expr_3.test(id: BBDD802E-8976-4D93-A6E2-1D43442EA9CD, name: "Jack", lastName: "Sparrow"))`

Hope this helps...

Comment: I edited my question with screenshots that may help clarify the problem. Print does show the properly initialized struct, but the debugger still shows it as nil.